# MSO remove extra space before & after text

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a button with the text "confirm your email now" and it will redirect to google website. I was able to get everything right but the width seems to be an issue as I am testing on one version of outlook it working perfectly but if test the same on other version there seems to be extra spacing before and after the text in the box.

I have tried applying margin and padding to zero, still the issue didn't resolve.

I want zero padding, there should be no empty spacing before the text 'confirm' and after the text 'now'

```html
<div>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.google.com" style="height:50px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:260px;" arcsize="12%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#686262">
        <w:anchorlock/>
        <center>
            <span style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;line-height:50px;margin:0;padding:0;">Confirm your email now</span>
        </center>
    </v:roundrect>
    <![endif]>
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background-color:#686262;border-radius:6px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:50px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">Confirm your email now</a>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```

[image: Outlook version 1]
[image: Outlook version 2]

Comment: I’m pretty sure the issue is Outlook itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a framework specifically designed for email compatibility.

Some notable frameworks include [MJML by Mailjet](https://mjml.io/) and a newer one, [Maizle (based on Twilwind classes)](https://maizzle.com/) and these help ensure your email renders correctly across  most email clients.